# Auto recognizing of shapes and measuring length and width

Tags: imagej

I'm sure it must be pretty simple but I've been breaking my head over it in the last few days.
Have a set of images with different straight-edged shapes. Running into two issues

1.After I threshold the image I select one of the shapes with the wand. But when I measure it I get the length and width of the bounding rectangle. Isn't there a way for ImageJ to straighten the object and measure it accurately?

2.Is there a way to write a macro that will auto analyze all the images and recognize and measure each shape?

Here is an example image:
http://postimg.org/image/yc78dkxmr/

Comment: General usage questions like this are much better asked on the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.net/list.html), where the chances of getting a helpful answer from an ImageJ expert are much higher.

Comment: Have you looked at the [_Measurements_ section](http://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub:Set-Measurements...) of the ImageJ user guide and the help for [batch processing](http://fiji.sc/Batch_Processing) many images? If you have a specific code question, feel free to post it here at _stackoverflow.com_.

Comment: Sorry about that :) Will post the question on the other ImageJ mailing list. Might have a specific code question but I'll keep it for later.